# Upload Image and Save Url with Struts

Tags: java, struts2

i have some code to upload image to server with struts2.After upload i want to show my image as thumbnail image and send path of image which i have uploaded to database.I confuse how make it can works

This is my Action Code.Cimande Action is extend from ActionSupport .

```
package com.maetrika.jagatoko.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilePermission;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.blueoxygen.cimande.commons.CimandeAction;

public class FileUpload extends CimandeAction{

    private File upload;
    private String uploadContentType;
    private String uploadFileName;
    private String fileCaption;

    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    File file;

    public String execute() throws Exception{

        try{

        //String filePath=servletRequest.getRealPath("/");
            String filePath=servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            File fileToCreate=new File(filePath, this.uploadFileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(upload, fileToCreate);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return INPUT;
            // TODO: handle exception
        }



        return SUCCESS;
    }






    public File getUpload() {

        return upload;
    }

    public void setUpload(File upload) {
        this.upload = upload;
    }

    public String getUploadContentType() {
        return uploadContentType;
    }

    public void setUploadContentType(String uploadContentType) {
        this.uploadContentType = uploadContentType;
    }

    public String getUploadFileName() {

        System.out.println("=======================" + uploadFileName);
        return uploadFileName;

    }

    public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
        this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
    }

    public String getFileCaption() {
        return fileCaption;
    }

    public void setFileCaption(String fileCaption) {
        this.fileCaption = fileCaption;
    }



    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
        return servletRequest;
    }



    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }



    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }



    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }


}
```

I use velocity for view.
This is my code for Upload Image

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Upload Gambar Produk</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="upload"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm newbie on java programming.Help me please..

Comment: You may try **[Image Plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/image-plugin.html)** (Third Party) of Struts2.

Comment: how can we do this in android for a .net server?

Answer (score 2):

You have to store in databse only the images name, generated as timestamp in miliseconds to avoid duplicates

```
    String fileName = myFile.getFileName();
    String extension = "";

    if (fileName != null && !fileName.equals("")) {
        extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."), fileName.length());
    }

    long longName = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); //date in miliseconds
    String newFileName = longName + extension;
```

Now you want to store images in your project for future use. To do that, make in your root folder, a folder named userimages, your Action code will look like that:

```
String uploadFolder = "userimages";
String filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + uploadFolder;

/* Save file on the server */
    if (!fileName.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);

        //Create file
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, newFileName);

        //If file does not exists, create file
        if (!fileToCreate.exists()) {
            FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreate);
            fileOutStream.write(myFile.getFileData());
            fileOutStream.flush();
            fileOutStream.close();
        }

    }
```

Now, to show up images in your jsp's, you need to use EL

Something like that:

```
 <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userimages/${imagename}"/>
```

I hope that helped you